# JS отличие между обычной и prototype функцией

Tags: javascript, jquery

Объясните пожалуйста в чем отличие между прототипом функцией и функцией, а именно будет ли в данных примерах отличие в используемой памяти компьютера.
К примеру есть 2 примера функций:

```
function TEST() {
    //тут какие-то большие действия
    console.log($(this).text())
}

$(document).on('click', 'li', TEST)
```

и с прототипом:

```
function Li(el) {
    this.el = el
}

Li.prototype.showText = function () {
    //тут какие-то большие действия
    console.log(this.el.text())
}

$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    var init = new Li($(this))
    init.showText()
})
```

И еще где хранится функция из первого примера в элементе? К примеру в Chrome в proto я могу найти функцию showText из 2 примера, а TEST функцию из 1 не могу, где она хранится? Вообщем буду благодарен за разъяснения!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Похоже вы совсем не понимаете, что такое функция в JavaScript. Давайте попробуем ликвидировать этот пробел в ваших знаниях.

1. Любая функция имеет свойство `prototype`.

   ```
   var f = function() {};
   console.log('prototype' in f); // true
   ```
2. Значением свойства `prototype` по-умолчанию является пустой объект.

   ```
   var f = function() {};
   console.log(f.prototype instanceof Object); // true
   console.log(Object.keys(f.prototype).length); // 0
   ```
3. Любую функцию можно использовать в качестве конструктора (хотя, если очень захотеть, то можно заканчивать любой вызов функции с оператором `new` ошибкой).

   ```
   var f = function() {};
   var t = new f();
   console.log(t instanceof f); // true
   ```
4. Функция это объект.

   ```
   var f = function() {}
   console.log(f instanceof Object); // true
   ```
5. Присваивание и передача объектов в JavaScript осуществляется по ссылке.

   ```
   var a = {test: 11};
   var b = a;
   b.test = 'changed';
   console.log(a.test); // 'changed'
   ```
6. Внутреннее свойство `__proto__` объект получает значение из `prototype`  свойства функции при создании с использованием `new`. Это свойство есть только у **объектов**. Дополнительно, стоит отметить, что свойство `__proto__` не является частью стандарта ECMAScript и доступно не во всех реализациях JS. ES2015 вводит метод `Object.getPrototypeOf`, который можно использовать вместо `__proto__`.

   ```
   var f = function() {};
   f.prototype = {test: 'value'};

   var o = new f();
   console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === f.prototype); // true
   ```

А теперь, вооружившись этими знаниями вернемся к вашим вопросам.

> в чем отличие между прототипом функцией и функцией

В значении свойства `prototype`. И все.

> будет ли в данных примерах отличие в используемой памяти компьютера

Во втором случае памяти нужно больше. Связанно это с необходимостью хранить экземпляр созданного объекта + несколько связей между объектами. **НО** разница между приведенными вами примерами настолько незначительна, что экономии памяти вы не увидите. Как следствие, перестаньте заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией и пишите максимально качественный/понятный код.

> И еще где хранится функция из первого примера в элементе? К примеру в Chrome в proto я могу найти функцию showText из 2 примера, а TEST функцию из 1 не могу, где она хранится?

Обе функции хранятся в памяти. А вот **ссылки на эти функции** хранятся в разных местах. В свойстве `__proto__` объекта, созданного с использованием конструктора `Li` храниться ссылка на функцию из второго примера. С первым примером все немного сложнее. Поскольку в данном случае функция создается в глобальной области видимости, то основная ссылка на функцию храниться в **глобальном** объекте. Для браузера глобальным объектом является объект `window`. Кроме того, ссылка на функцию доступна через переменную `f`:

```
function f() {};
console.log('f' in window); // true
console.log(typeof window.f === 'function'); // true
console.log(window.f === f); // true
```

**Резюме**: Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией, варианты почти одинаковы по используемой памяти.

Comment: Так почему же в `__proto__` нет ссылки на функцию TEST из первого примера? Очень интересно)

Comment: Вообще TEST создан в глобальной области видимости. она находится в объекте window. создаем `function TEST() {alert('abc');}`, вызываем `window.TEST()`. И console.log('TEST' in window) конечно даст true

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добавил п.6 в ответ.

Comment: @Mike, вы правы, дополнил ответ. Хотя, стоит заметить, что в объекте `window` храниться только ссылка на функцию `TEST`. Можно проверить вот так: `function f() {}; var a = window.f; delete window.f; console.log(typeof a === 'function');`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Кстати хочу заметить, что по книге на http://learn.javascript.ru/new-prototype и в п.2 вашего ответа не сходится. так как в книге говорится, что в prototype по умолчанию есть свойство constructor

Comment: @user3737786, хорошее  замечание. Но тут есть одна тонкость. Не все свойства объектов являются собственными и перечесляемыми (`toString`, `valueOf`, `hasOwnProperty`). `constructor` как раз и относится к таким свойствам. В п.2 правильнее было бы сказать, что прототип по-умолчанию и не имеет собственных перечислимых свойств, однако я нарочно опустил этот момент, чтобы не усложнять описание базовых принципов. Вообще тема создания объектов в JS и наследования довольно обширна, думаю вам стоит почитать что-то из классических книг, например Флэнагана.